# How to execute the asynchronous task several times?

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I want to execute the asynchronous task several times based on the size of the list. How this can be achieved? I want to change the parameters too every time ..

Comment: putting code here can help you

Comment: keep a loop which iterates through list size and call the asynchronous task in loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the list size and call asynchronous task  in that.

```
for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++)
{
     // Call AsyncTask with any value you want to pass
     // just generate a constructor accordingly

     new AsyncTask(i).execute();  
}
```

And get the value in `AsyncTask` class with required constructor :

```
 public class AsyncTask{

        Integer position;
        public AsyncTask(Integer passedValue)
        {
            position = passedValue;
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps ツ

Comment: If you are likely to launch a high number of AsyncTask at the same time, I recommend the use of task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);